# EXTJS: Month/Day Selector (ie. no year)

Tags: extjs, picker

I am currently using a EXTJS EditorGridPanel in my application, and for one of the column inputs I require the user to be able to pick a month and day (no year).

I am currently using a DateField to do this, but I need to be able to disable the "year" aspect of it in the UI.  I do not care if the "value" in the end has a year associated with it, I can simply disregard it.  I have searched to see if anyone has done such a thing, but my only findings are people that way to show only Month/Year.

My other option is to create my own custom input (with comboboxes for month and day, where the day combo changes based on the month), however, I honestly don't have all that much time to make one myself as I would have to go through the learning curve since I have never created a custom input extension before.

--> So my big question then is, has anyone heard of an existing EXTJS month/day picker?

Any help would be much appropriated stack overflow peoples!

Comment: Actually thinking about this, it makes no sense to have a Month/Day picker in calendar form, as the layout of the days on each day of the week will have no meaning.  I guess what I really want is an existing month/day combobox picker (where the number of days will change depending on which month is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I would probably create my own custom component to use as the editor, if you're not comfortable doing that, have you considered breaking the Month and Day fields into separate columns in your grid column model?

Another option would be to add a input mask to the textfield (you'll need to specify one as a customEditor in your cm).  I believe this is done via custom vtypes.  This input mask would force the user to enter the date in the format that you specify.

Using this approach would :

1. keep all month/day data in one column
2. simplifies your UI code by using the out-of-the-box components. (IMO this is key for learning ExtJS)

Comment: I thought about separate columns, but that would give my grid a total of 11 columns which seems borderline "too many".  I will look into input masking, it was not an option I had thought of.  Thank you!

Comment: We ended up not needing the control after all, however, after thinking back over the original issue - creating a custom component would have been the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
{
    xtype: 'datepickerfield',
    name: 'OrderDate',
    label: 'Order Date',
    picker: { yearTo: 2011, yearFrom: 2020 }
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Why do you think the year will be disabled in your solution?

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
  picker: {
    slotOrder: [ 'month', 'day' ]
  }
```

Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Comment: If I need to revisit the control (we ended up not needing it after all), I will have a look and see if this solution works - thank you!